# How to turn off the icons in a SharePoint standard List?

Tags: list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I found nothing about this icons. How can I hide it? Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Which icon do you mean, can you provide a screenshot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to hide the icons on modern experience list forms using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

These icons are specific to column type you are using in your list.

**Example**: Single line of text, Choice, Number, etc.

The icon you highlighted is related to the **Yes/No** column in SharePoint:

[image]

---

You can hide those by customizing the list for using Power Apps: [Customize a Microsoft Lists or SharePoint form by using Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form)

But, I don't think it is worth to do it using Power Apps just to hide the icon which is SharePoint default functionality.